# how to set user ID in Realtime database the same in user ID in Authentication?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, authentication, firebase-realtime-database

Can you help me with my issue? I want to set the IDs in the real-time database the same as the user ID in the Authentication when the user sign - up successfully in my app. I will use the user ID to retrieve the data of the user from my app. It's like the user will see his data from a Profile Activity. May I ask how to do it?

Here's my code from my SIGN-UP Activity

```
package com.example.biowit;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class Bio_SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {


EditText txtbx_SU_FullName, txtbx_SU_CPNum, txtbx_SU_Email, txtbx_SU_Pass, txtbx_SU_ConfirmPass; // edit text declarations
Button btn_Register; // button/s declaration/s
ImageButton btn_SU_Back;
FirebaseAuth FbaseAuth_SU; //for authentication
FirebaseDatabase rootNode; // for realtime database
DatabaseReference reference;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // hides the title bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getSupportActionBar().hide(); // hides the action bar

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bio_sign_up);

    txtbx_SU_FullName = findViewById(R.id.txtbx_SU_FullName);
    txtbx_SU_Email = findViewById(R.id.txtbx_SU_Email);
    txtbx_SU_CPNum = findViewById(R.id.txtbx_SU_CPNum);
    txtbx_SU_Pass = findViewById(R.id.txtbx_SU_Pass);
    txtbx_SU_ConfirmPass = findViewById(R.id.txtbx_SU_ConfirmPass);
    btn_Register = findViewById(R.id.btn_Register);
    btn_SU_Back = findViewById(R.id.btn_SU_Back);

    FbaseAuth_SU = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://biowit-log-in-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/");
    reference = rootNode.getReference("users");

    btn_Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String fullname = txtbx_SU_FullName.getText().toString();
            String email = txtbx_SU_Email.getText().toString();
            String cpnum = txtbx_SU_CPNum.getText().toString();
            String password = txtbx_SU_Pass.getText().toString();
            String ConPassword = txtbx_SU_ConfirmPass.getText().toString();
            String UserID = FbaseAuth_SU.getUid();
            UserHelper UHelper = new UserHelper(fullname, cpnum, email, password);

            if(fullname.isEmpty()){ // condition if full name field is empty,
                txtbx_SU_FullName.setError("This field cannot be empty."); // this error message will be shown.
                return;
            }

            if(cpnum.isEmpty()){ // condition if full name field is empty,
                txtbx_SU_CPNum.setError("This field cannot be empty."); // this error message will be shown.
                return;
            }

            if(email.isEmpty()){ // condition if full name field is empty,
                txtbx_SU_Email.setError("This field cannot be empty."); // this error message will be shown.
                return;
            }

            if(password.isEmpty()){ // condition if full name field is empty,
                txtbx_SU_Pass.setError("This field cannot be empty."); // this error message will be shown.
                return;
            }

            if(ConPassword.isEmpty()){ // condition if full name field is empty,
                txtbx_SU_ConfirmPass.setError("This field cannot be empty."); // this error message will be shown.
                return;
            }

            if (!ConPassword.equals(password)){ // condition if the confirm password is not equals to password,
                txtbx_SU_ConfirmPass.setError("Password does not match."); // this error message will be shown.
                return;
            }

            // notification that says the data is validated.
            Toast.makeText(Bio_SignUp.this, "Data Validated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Email address and password authentication in the database.
            FbaseAuth_SU.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) { // send the user to the log - in screen.

                    reference.child(UserID).setValue(UHelper).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void unused) { // notification that the user was successfully registered.
                            Toast.makeText(Bio_SignUp.this, "Sign - up Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {  // when user failed to sign up, an error message shows.
                            Toast.makeText(Bio_SignUp.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    });

                    startActivity(new Intent(Bio_SignUp.this, Bio_LogIn.class));
                }

            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) { // an error when email and pass is wrong or invalid.
                    Toast.makeText(Bio_SignUp.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    btn_SU_Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `String UserID = FbaseAuth_SU.getUid();` when no user is logged in then it's probably going to return null. Instead get UID of the user after they have logged in using [`getUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo) and `getUid` methods:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
  String userUID = authResult.getUser().getUid()
  Toast.makeText(Bio_SignUp.this, userUID.getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 
  //Now add data to Realtime Database
  reference.child(userUID).setValue(UHelper) 
}
```

Comment: so the currently signed in user must log-in in order to get set its id from real db the same as auth user ID?

Comment: @ThredgePaul if you want UID (or any data) of currently logged in user then yes they must be logged in.

Answer (score 2):

okay so you can always format the database however you want but the code below will set the users full name, email, password and number under a child named "users" and within that child "users" will be another child with the userId as the key set this code after the user is created and you can set an onSuccessListener after setValue to do what you please:

```
UserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("full_name", fullname);
map.put("email", email);
map.put("password", password);
map.put("number", cpnum);

reference.child("users").child(UserID).setValue(map);
```